How to find the inverse of this linear integral operator?
Let $f(x): \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that decays ``fastly enough'' at infinity.
We can define the following linear operator
$$L[f](x):= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} d^d y \, \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{d+\sigma}} \, + \, K \,\frac{f(x)}{|x_\perp|^\sigma}$$
where $\sigma$ is some negative real number, so that the integral is well defined (as long as $f(x)$ decays rapidly at infinity), $K$ is a real constant, and $|x_\perp|$ is the distance from the point $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ to the line defined by $x_1=0$ (so $x_\perp = (0,x_2,\dots,x_d)$ ).
Is it possible to express the inverse of this operator in a way that gives some analytical (or even numerical) control over it? For example, I'm thinking of an integral representation or a convergent series representation where the terms are known.
I've tried the following: let's give a name to the two terms
$$ A[f](x):= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} d^d y \, \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{d+\sigma}}\,, \quad B[f](x):= K \,\frac{f(x)}{|x_\perp|^\sigma}\,, \quad \Rightarrow \,  L=A+B\,.$$
Now the operator $A$ is diagonal after a Fourier transform, indeed it acts on plane waves  as $A[e^{ip \cdot x}](x) \propto|p|^\sigma e^{ip\cdot x}$, and it can be easily inverted.
At least formally, I can write
$$ L^{-1}=(A+B)^{-1}=(A^{-1}-A^{-1} B A^{-1} + A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1} - \ldots)\,. $$
The problem with this method (besides convergence issues that I've not yet addressed) is that even though I know what $A^{-1}$ and $B$ are, the composition of operators like $A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}\!\!\dots\,$ involves nested integrals that I'm not able to simplify.
Do you know if this problem (or a similar one) is already addressed in the literature? Or do you know some technique that I can try to use?
`
